# acts_as_attachment and Capistrano problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

currently i am using acts_as_attachment and also using Capistrano. I want to store images in shared path rather than current path. 
I want set path during create action
What should i do ?????
Please code is more helpful

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
after "deploy:symlink", :copy_images

task :copy_images do
  desc "Copy images to shared folder"
  run "cp -rb /[your path]/public/images /[your path]/shared/"
end
```

Comment: I want set path during create action